# Stopping criteria for pre-made estimators in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I have a question about TensorFlow's estimators in `tf.estimator`, in particular `DNNClassifier`. It says in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.7/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier):

> `max_steps`: Number of total steps for which to train model. If `None`, train forever or train until `input_fn` generates the `OutOfRange` error or `StopIteration` exception

In the doc on [datasets for estimators](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets_for_estimators) it mentions that for training you need to use the `shuffle()`, `repeat()`, and `batch_size` methods, so that the iterator on the data set does stop after it's gone through the data once.

Does this mean that the pre-made estimators such as `DNNClassifier` have no stopping criterion based on the learning rate or changes in the loss? Is it really the case you can only have these models stop training based on how you specify the input function or by giving a maximum number of steps?

Answer (score 0):

TensforFlow will not presume to know upon what learning rate or loss it should stop at.  This is reasonable because they're problem-dependent.  You could reasonably argue that it could infer a sensible limit based on round-off error for the given data types (if they're consistent, e.g. float32) but then many problems should be stopped earlier.  So there is no sensible, broadly applicable default.

However, you can control this behaviour yourself using callbacks.  TensorFlow includes the `EarlyStopping` callback.  You can find the (python) documentation for it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping).